# How to implement Google ReCaptcha in Ajax pop up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I am working in MVC3.0 and I want to implement Captcha (Google service) on a pop up. Now the problem is the pop up is made by ajax call.

In AJAX call the pop up Re captcha is not coming but in a normal pop up it is coming correctly.

I followed the following steps:

Step 1: I included this in Email.cshtml

```
@Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
```

Step 2: Generate this function in my .cs file:

```
public static string GenerateCaptcha(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var captchaControl = new RecaptchaControl
    {
        ID = "recaptcha",
        Theme = "clean", //http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/Theme
        PublicKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReCaptchaPublicKey"],
        PrivateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReCaptchaPrivateKey"]
    };
    var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
    captchaControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    return htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
}
```

Step 3: Then add public and private key in web.config and also add the necessary namespace

I followed all the steps.

Can someone please suggest if pop up is made by Ajax call and if I have to implement captcha in Ajax pop up then what do I have to do?

Regards,
Sahil

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha#Client_Side_(How_to_make_the_CAPTCHA_image_show_up)